# Prevent javascript-initiated scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

There are many questions about preventing user-initiated (i.e., mouse, touch, keyboard) scrolling via javascript.  In this case, I am creating a component within a CMS that needs to stop another CMS component from scrolling itself into view.  I do not have access to the other CMS component's code (which is also heavily obfuscated).

I have tried disabling typical ways of forcing scrolling with the following code, yet the other CMS still scrolls into view, a second or two after the following code runs:

```
  Element.prototype.scrollIntoView = function(alignWithTop){
    console.log("******** scrollIntoView: " + this.getAttribute("id"));
  };

  Element.prototype.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded = function(alignWithTop){
    console.log("******** scrollIntoViewIfNeeded: " + this.getAttribute("id"));
  };

  Element.prototype.scrollByLines = function(){
    console.log("******** scrollByLines: " + this.getAttribute("id"));
  };

  Element.prototype.scrollByPages = function(){
    console.log("******** scrollByPages: " + this.getAttribute("id"));
  };

  Element.prototype.focus = function(){
    console.log("******** focus: " + this.getAttribute("id"));
  };

  window.scroll = function(xpos,ypos){
    console.log("******** scroll: " + xpos+","+ypos);
  }

  window.scrollTo = function(xpos,ypos){
    console.log("******** scrollTo: " + xpos+","+ypos);
  }

  window.scrollBy = function(xpos,ypos){
    console.log("******** scrollBy: " + xpos+","+ypos);
  }

  jQuery.fn.scrollTop = function(){
    console.log("!!!!!!!! scrollTop");
  };

  jQuery.fn.animate = function(){
    console.log("!!!!!!!! animate");
  };

  jQuery.fn.click = function(){
    console.log("!!!!!!!! click");
  };
```

I can set `window.onscroll` to force a call to `window.scrollTo(0,0)` for a period of time, but that seems unsatisfactory since it looks jumpy and prevents user-initiated scrolling, which I do not want to prevent.

Is there some other way javascript (or jQuery) can force a scroll that I am missing in the above code?

Comment: "Scrolling itself into view" - Is it an animation effect like fade-in or something?

Comment: try returning false when you you think it shouldn't scroll.

Comment: By "Scrolling itself into view" I mean that my component should be at the top of the page, with the CMS-supplied component below, nominally scrolled off the bottom of the page.  But when it loads, the CMS-supplied component scrolls up into view.

Answer (score 1):

So this should have been obvious, but the function the CMS was calling was `HTMLElementObject.focus()`, so the following is the code I used to stop the unwanted scrolling during page load and setup:

```
// Stop the page from jumping around for a little while
var oldFocus = Element.prototype.focus;
Element.prototype.focus = function(){};
setTimeout(
  function(){
    Element.prototype.focus = oldFocus;
  },5000);
```